# Concept of encapsulation

Tags: java, oop

Encapsulation - relying on the Java bean pattern of getters and setters for every field isn't encapsulating anything

Comment: What tells you can the setter changes a variable? Nothing. The class can ignore the setter. Encapsulation.

Comment: @BoristheSpider A setter is, by definition, changing a field. It's fair enough to sometimes have methods which mutable the state of an object, obviously, but someone whose relying on the Java bean pattern of getters and setters for every field is fooling themselves if they think they're encapsulating anything.

Answer (score 2):

You're correct. If a field is exposed via getters and setters, it is **not** encapsulated. It's annoying how many people don't understand this so it's not surprising that you're confused.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19044735/303810) states the exact opposite.

Comment: @lexicore Yep. Because he's wrong. This article explains it best: http://www.yegor256.com/2016/11/21/naked-data.html

Comment: @lexicore Also check out [Is encapsulation still one of the elephants OOP stands on?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/358611/is-encapsulation-still-one-of-the-elephants-oop-stands-on)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19044362/java-encapsulation-concept-not-clear). Essentially, using the keyword `private` we are able to prevent outside use of the fields in a class, for example. It hides the data in a class associated with that `private` keyword.